# Red5 demo simpleBroadcast cannot work: Adobe Flash Player does not go through "allow"

Tags: red5

I am testing Red5 demo simpleBroadcast

### Click "Connect" Button, pops up a window:

Adobe Flash Player Settings
Camera and Microphone Access localhost is requesting access to your camera and microphone. If you click Allow, you may be recorded.

### two buttons: Allow, Deny.

But if I click Allow button, nothing happened. Actually it seems this small popped winodw does not work.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04
Adobe flash player:   package: flashplugin-installer, 11.2.202.394ubuntu0.12.04.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug present in Flash Player and not fixed by Adobe since years.

As a workaround you could instruct the users of your site to visit the [Website Privacy Settings panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager06.html) and **Always allow** your site:

[image: screenshot]

Then the problematic window won't pop up anymore.